# Clone items with new id

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have table `SnapshotCompaniesHouseSearchResults` and related table  `SnapshotCompaniesHousePreviousNames`

Here is diagram

[image]

I need to write logic for clonning `SnapshotCompaniesHouseSearchResults`

So I wrote method like this

```
 private async Task CopySnapshotCompanyHouseData(Guid jobIdOld, Guid jobIdNew)
    {
        var snapshotData =
            await _dbContext.SnapshotCompaniesHouseSearchResults.Where(x => x.JobId == jobIdOld)
                .Include(x => x.SnapshotCompaniesHousePreviousNames)
                .ToListAsync();

        foreach (var file in snapshotData)
        {
            file.JobId = jobIdNew;
        }

        await _dbContext.AbleBulkInsertAsync(snapshotData);
    }
```

Here is AbleBulkInsertAsync method code

```
 public static async Task AbleBulkInsertAsync<T>(this DbContext dbContext, List<T> entities, int pageSize = 1000) where T : class
    {
        int pageNumber = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var page = entities.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            if (page.Count == 0) return;

            await dbContext.BulkInsertAsync(page, new BulkConfig { BulkCopyTimeout = 0 });
            pageNumber++;
        }
    }
```

My problem is I need to save related collection values, but with new parent item Id.

How I can do this?

Comment: It's not clear what's happening. Is nothing being updated? Do you need a `SaveChanges`?

Comment: I think you have to add `IncludeGraph = true` check [here for reference](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert)